# Cant use flutter_bloc for some reason

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

So I am running Android Studio 4.2.1.

I can create a "New Flutter Project", and run it.

As an aside, I have built a few learning apps as I go along.

But for some reason if I "import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';", it chokes.

Here is the console output:

> Launching lib/main.dart on I3312 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> ../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-7.0.0/lib/src/bloc.dart:96:28:
> Error: The argument type 'Event' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object' because
> 'Event' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   observer.onEvent(this, event);
>   ^

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Here is the "offending code from bloc.dart:

````
  /// A great spot to add logging/analytics at the individual [Bloc] level.
  ///
  /// **Note: `super.onEvent` should always be called first.**
  /// ```dart
  /// @override
  /// void onEvent(Event event) {
  ///   // Always call super.onEvent with the current event
  ///   super.onEvent(event);
  ///
  ///   // Custom onEvent logic goes here
  /// }
  /// ```
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  /// * [BlocObserver.onEvent] for observing events globally.
  ///
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void onEvent(Event event) {
    // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
    observer.onEvent(this, event);
  }
````

Any project that I download that has uses flutter_bloc has some error or another.

I have a feeling this has to do with "null safety" but I dont know.

cheers

edit; added pubspec.yaml

```
name: simple_bloc
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
#  sdk:  ">=2.7.0 <=2.10.0"
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <=3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: it seems to me that you are using an old flutter_bloc version with dart 2.12 (aka null safety). Could you post your pubspec.yaml

Comment: Added to the original post. - thanks

Comment: As an aside... I just installed Android Studio on my Windows PC, and it works there.

So, obviously something I did to the environment on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Tried reinstalling Android Studio, but it did not work.

Finally tried "COMPLETELY" delete AndroidStudio and any other Android, com.google folder on my Mac...

Reinstalled Android Studio, Flutter SDK and Android SDK.

That worked, but it was a PITA!